# WordPress: Trying to create a one-page scroll navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Okay, I am trying to create a simple navigation. However when I convert my html/css to wordpress site I cannot get it to work since I have to use `<?php wp_nav_menu( $args) ?>`

Here is what I have html

```
<nav class="header-nav">
            <!-- Create a navigation called primary in the header (front-end) -->

            <?php $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary'); ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( $args) ?>
</nav>
```

**Problem:** In my html/css mockup site I would simply give each `a` item an id and use javascript to add binding -View depending on which `a` item is clicked. Here is the script.

Js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // add a click listener to each <a> tags
    setBindings();

    // burger nav
    jQuery(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".header-nav").toggleClass("open");  
    });

});

/* ONE PAGE NAVIGATION FUNCTION */
function setBindings() {
    jQuery(".header-nav a.scrollLink").click(function(e) {
        // prevent anchor tags for working (?)
        e.preventDefault();
        var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id + "-View";

        jQuery("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#" + sectionID).offset().top
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

**Wordpress:** In my wordpress, I have created the menu and in the link section I have created a menu with div id, however to get the animation to work i need javascript to work. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**Question: How to I add ids to my nav `a` tags Since Wordpress renders it own html navigation when I use `wp_nav_menu( $args)`?**

ideas?

**UPDATE** This is what Im trying to replicate in WordPress (this is my html version of navigation with the ids to `a` tags that make my script scroll animated)

```
        <ul class="header-nav">
            <li><a id="home" class="scrollLink" href="#home-View">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="about" class="scrollLink" href="#about-View">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a id="contact"  class="scrollLink" href="#contact-View">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: So the IDs of your sections that you want to jump to correspond with the hash used in the anchor? Then what would you need IDs on the LI elements for?

Comment: Okay, my mistake, ids are assigned only to a tag not list. Fixed the question

Comment: The problem is simple: In wordpress you must use <?php $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary'); ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( $args) ?> to add navigation menu and therefore I don't have an html nav structure in the page to add ids to to make javascript work!

Comment: What makes you think you need to add IDs to make this work? You have `#about` in the href of your anchor element, and you have a section with the ID `about-View` somewhere on your page, correct? Where’s the need for any additional IDs then?

Comment: Please check the question I've added the html version of what I want (IDs on a tag). Essentially since wordpress renders its own nav I can't add the ids needed to add animated scroll (my js script). At the moment it goes to the right section, but its not animated scroll.

Comment: As I keep telling you, you don’t _need_ what you “want”. You have all the necessary data right there, you don’t need additional IDs. All you need to do when the link is clicked, is the get content of its hash, and then use that to select the section with the corresponding id.

Comment: Okay, I understand your point, I just need to change my javascript function to select the a class rendered by wordpres html (using inspect element)?. I have tried to select the a tag like this: jQuery(".menu li a").click(function(e) however it not being selected. Any ideas how I can select the a tag, here is the blog link www.radian3.com

Comment: The menu already has an id, so you can use that to select the links inside it. (But the links on your example page currently are not anchor links.)

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I've fixed it. Each page has an id instead of a link. Here is the link: http://radian3.com/#contact still don't know how to select the correct id for the script. Please check. Thank

Comment: Well if you are mixing anchor links and “normal” links, you first of all need to find a way to distinguish between both. I’d suggest you add a class to those links, like you had in your example HTML already - that is possible directly via WP default functionality, you just need to make the class input field visible by adapting the view settings on top of the menu edit page.

Comment: Then, if you don’t know how to get the hash of the link - time for a little bit of research ... https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+get+hash+of+clicked+anchor

Comment: Alright, will be looking at it! Thanks for you help :)